# Inconsistency in pandas aggregate with custom function or not?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregate

I think I found an anomaly with pandas.Series.agg method.

Here's what I found.

```
>>> v = pd.Series([172, 172, 170.0, 170., 168.])
>>> 
>>> v.agg(np.mean)
170.4
>>> 
>>> v.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
0    172.0
1    172.0
2    170.0
3    170.0
4    168.0
dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> np.mean(v)
170.4
```

I found this frustrating because `lambda x: f(x)` should work just the same as `f(x)`, right? And input to `.agg(func)` is Series (according to documentation) but the output shows it is not. Here's another output.

```
>>> v.agg(lambda x: print(type(x)))
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
0    None
1    None
0    None
1    None
0    None
dtype: object

>>> v.agg(lambda x: print(x.tolist()))
[172.0, 172.0, 170.0, 170.0, 168.0]
```

what? The output suggest that input to `lambda x:` is different for the two case above. I am not sure even if it's possible.

Here's what I got from further investigation.

```
>>> v.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
0    172.0
1    172.0
0    170.0
1    170.0
0    168.0
dtype: float64
>>> v.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
0    170.0
1    171.0
dtype: float64
>>> v.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x.tolist()))
170.4
```

At least, `lambda x: np.mean(x)` works as expected for grouped Series! but the mystery still remains. Could anyone help me clarify what is going on here?

I test with pandas.DataFrame.agg with `lambda x: np.mean(x)` and it works as expected!

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(v)
       0
0  172.0
1  172.0
0  170.0
1  170.0
0  168.0
>>> pd.DataFrame(v).agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
0    170.4
dtype: float64
```

====

To sum up, my question is that the result of the two below are the smae.

```
v.groupby(by = [0]*len(v)).agg(np.mean)
v.groupby(by = [0]*len(v)).agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

But the below two are not the same. Isn't it considered as **inconsistency** in pandas?

```
v.agg(np.mean)
v.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

And where does it come from?

Comment: Or it could be some peculiarity in `np.mean`. Here's another counterexample(?) 
`v.agg(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x))` works fine!

Comment: everything is working as expected so what is your question?

Comment: I vaguely recall from some earlier SO exploration, that `agg` redirects some common functions like `np.mean` to a special `pandas` version.  The `lambda x:mean(x)` would prevent that.  I assume that's documented in `agg`, but it not, it may require digging into the code.

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(v).agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))
0    170.4
```

The above looks fine to you, because it is being applied on `axis=0`, but if you pass `axis=1`, you'll get the same result as with Series:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(v).agg(lambda x: np.mean(x), axis=1)
0    172.0
1    172.0
2    170.0
3    170.0
4    168.0
dtype: float64
```

The thing is, DataFrames have two axes i.e. 0 and 1, but Series has only one axis i.e. 0.
When you're doing `v.agg(lambda x: np.mean(x))`, it is being applied on Series for each individual values separately which is similar to `pandas.Series.apply` , versus when you are doing `v.agg(np.mean)` it is applied to the entire Series.

Looking at [`docs for pandas.Series.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

> **Parameters**: func: function, str, list or dict 
>  Function to use for
> aggregating the data. If a function, must either work when passed a
> Series **or when passed to Series.apply**.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question. `np.mean(v)` and `(lambda x: np.mean(x))(v)` both produce the same result for my example`v`. So if we consider only the input and the output of function, both are the same. But the result of v.agg(f) is different. And also `v.apply(np.mean)` and `v.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x)` are the same!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source of `agg`. The method checks whether the passed function is vectorized and then returns a scalar, or if it isn't, applies it on each row

> ```
>         # try a regular apply, this evaluates lambdas
>         # row-by-row; however if the lambda is expected a Series
>         # expression, e.g.: lambda x: x-x.quantile(0.25)
>         # this will fail, so we can try a vectorized evaluation
>
>         # we cannot FIRST try the vectorized evaluation, because
>         # then .agg and .apply would have different semantics if the
>         # operation is actually defined on the Series, e.g. str
> ```

This is why you have an error when combining transformation and aggregation functions:

```
>>> v.agg([np.mean, lambda x: np.mean(x)])
ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations
```

Answer (score 2):

Agg is "probing" the function by calling it in different ways and sometimes that goes wrong. Here's how I've solved it for the case of `scipy.stats.iqr`:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

df = <some dataframe>

df.agg(scipy.stats.iqr)  # ok
df.agg(["mean", scipy.stats.iqr])  # !! ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations
```

If we make a wrapper that *only* handles arrays and not scalars, it will work!

```py
import functools

def only_vector(f):
    "decorator: the function raises ValueError if arg is not an array"
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(arg, *args, **kwargs):
        if np.shape(arg) == ():
            raise ValueError("Expected vector argument")
        return f(arg, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

```py
iqr = only_vector(scipy.stats.iqr)
df.agg(["mean", iqr])  # OK
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround ;)